# Error method InputStreamReader (InputStream)

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to make switch case in Java. After all i wrote the code i'm facing this problem. I tried to figure out but I don't get it.

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.*;

class question3 {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);          
        InputStreamReader(System.in);

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);

        String str;
        int choice;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Number:");
        str = stdin.readLine();

        choice = Integer.parseInt(str);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You selected 1.");
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You selected 2 or 3.");
            break;
        case 4: System.out.println("You selected 4.");
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Select again please.");
        }
    }
}
```

Error in CMD :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:{PATH}>javac question3.java
question3.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                                InputStreamReader(System.in);

                                ^
  symbol:   method InputStreamReader(InputStream)
  location: class question3
1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of that line: `InputStreamReader(System.in);` (the 2nd line in `main`)

It does nothing for you. You already use `System.in` to initialize above that.

The compiler was expecting a variable to use your statement there, as you're calling the `InputStreamReader` constructor and not doing anything with the resulting object.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I appriciated it :)

Comment: @Edie Glad to help. (Note that you can only mark one answer as accepted and it is the usual custom to mark the one that helped you the most as the answer.)

Comment: No problem. The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is full of useful gems like that.

Comment: BTW, `Scanner(System.in);` is a far, far better way to do this.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Not that you're wrong, but note that he said in another comment that he cannot use `Scanner` due to restrictions set by his professor. This question is not about HOW to read an integer, but how to resolve his error.

Answer (score 1):

use scanner instead.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Number:");
    int choice= scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the error as is. His question is not about what method to read an integer, but about how to resolve the compilation error. (For other reference, you're correct; a scanner is much better suited here)

Comment: Yap. I need to remove what @Avery said. I cant use scanner because my lecture doesn't allow me to write coding with scanner. Because using scanner is easy for I/O.